# Excercise for Explicit Riemann Mapping

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Set $U:=\{ z\in \mathbb{C}\mid \arg(z)\in(-\alpha,\alpha)\}$ with $\alpha\in(0,\pi)$.Give explicitly the conformal mapping $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ such that $f(U)=\mathbb{D}$ with $f(1)=0$ and $f'(1)>0$

This is one of many exercises for Riemann mapping. My idea is find a conformal function $g$ such that $g(U)=\mathbb{H}$ the superior half plane and take conformal mapping $h:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ (with the assumption indicated, $i.e.$ $h(z)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{z+i}{z-i}$). Since $\alpha\in(0,\pi)$, $g(z)=e^{i(\pi-\alpha)}z$ is biholomorphic between $U$ and $\mathbb{H}$. Take $f=g\circ h$ is alright?

Comment: Your $g$ is only biholomorphic between $U$ and the half-plane if $\alpha = \pi/2$. Generally, how do you transform an angular sector to a half-plane?

Comment: @DanielFischer You right, my function $g$ dont work for any $\alpha$. And $z\mapsto e^{i\alpha}z$ take the set $U$ and send it to $\{ z\mid 0<Arg(z)<2\alpha\}\subset\mathbb{H}$ but after that I dont know what to do.

Comment: How would you map the first quadrant conformally to the upper half-plane?

Comment: @DanielFischer $z\mapsto z^{\pi/\alpha}$?

Comment: That's for the general case, I suppose. Not quite, that maps to $-\pi < \operatorname{Arg} z < \pi$. But a power is right. Then you have a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ in $h$ that shouldn't be there, and $h$ maps the wrong half-plane into the disk, and you need $h\circ g$, not $g\circ h$. Check your details, but you're heading in the right direction.